# Mono on Apache 2.28 - vhosts does not function properly

Tags: apache-2.2, asp.net, virtualhost, mono

I installed Mono on Windows 7, followed the instructions at http://www.mono-project.com/Using_Mono_on_Windows#Using_Mono_on_Windows and the command prompt worked.

Mod_mono was added to httpd.conf, and theoreticlaly, it *should* work.

However, I want one of my vhosts to run asp.net via mod_mono.

Here it is:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.joebloggstest1.co.uk 
ServerAlias joebloggstest1.co.uk
DocumentRoot /www/joebloggstest1.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
    <Directory "/www/joebloggstest1.co.uk">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

I could not find how to do it for Windows on Google, only Linux/Ubuntu distros, which isn't useful for my situation.

mod_mono is installed, this is from httpd.conf:

```
Include conf/mod_mono.conf 
AddHandler mono .aspx .asp .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd

<Location /mono>
  SetHandler mono-ctrl
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

What would you do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.joebloggstest1.co.uk
  ServerAlias joebloggstest1.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /www/joebloggstest1.co.uk
  <Directory "/">
       Options All
       AllowOverride All
       order allow,deny
       allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You should put the directory tag inside the vHost tag.
Make sure your server will support execution of these scripts too.
ALSO: You should just do "directory as /" as noted above. Otherwise you'd have to go to joebloggstest1.couk/joebloggstest.co.uk.

Comment: Do you only want to allow access from 127.0.0.1? And at the top of httpd.conf, do you have a LoadModule mod_mono.so or something similar? ALSO: In windows, do not use /www/website. Do something like "C:\website\www.name.com\files" in quotes.

Comment: -1 for the `Directory "/"` suggestion - I think you've confused `Directory` and `Location`, and your suggestion that "you'd have to go to joebloggstest1.couk/joebloggstest.co.uk" is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use linux? It's not so difficult to setup a full working server on a distro with good mono packages support. I recommend using nginx (my personal choise) or apache.